# Is there a way to set contents of "GST Which" and "All amounts are" fields in sales receipt programatically?

Tags: .net, intuit-partner-platform, qbxml, sales-tax

Right now with the SDK when I add a sales receipt the "GST Which" and "All amounts are" fields require modification manually through the user interface and I don't know how to set them with the traditional SDK (QBXML). Is there a way to set these? Is it possible to do it with the REST api?

Comment: Not sure about how it works in QBSDK. You can refer QBD SalesReceipt API docs(REST) to see if it has what you want. docs.https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/salesreceipt . Thanks.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I will check out that page you have given. I am trying to work with QB online plus. They have recently gone global. There is a GST centre tab on the interface which if activated, activates certain fields on the sales receipt. Namely "GST Which" and "All amounts are". In "All Amounts are" you can specify either GST inclusive or exclusive. I want to specify something in here but can't seem to do it with qbxml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The traditional SDK for QBO does not support GST or the global model.

Comment: Hi William, thanks for your response. What about the new API? the REST v2, does that support GST/Global model?